# Making an Alarm application in iOS

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I am making an alarm application. When I set the alarm the notification fire immediately. I set two schedule notifications functions for alarm. One is for everyday repeat alarm and other is for weekly repeat alarm. My code for everyday repeat alarm is working fine but for weekly repeat alarm , notifications fire immediately and sometimes fire at different day.
Here is code for repeat alarm for weekly basis.

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithWeek:(NSDate *)fireDate
{

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotif.fireDate = calculateAlarmDay;
    NSLog(@"%@",localNotif.fireDate);
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake Up";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.soundName = @"Tick-tock-sound.mp3";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


}
```

and here is a code in which I calculate the day on which it fires e.g if user select sunday than it fires on sunday 28-2-2016 and than next sunday 6-3-2016 and so on..

```
-(void) repeataftersevendays:(int) day
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSLog(@"%@",components);
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    finalValue = 0;

    if (weekday == day)
    {
        finalValue=0;
    }
    else if (weekday < day)
    {
        int tempWeekDay = weekday;
        while ( tempWeekDay  < day )
        {
            tempWeekDay++;
            finalValue++;
            NSLog(@"%i",finalValue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int tempDay = day;
        while ( weekday  >= tempDay )
        {
            tempDay++;
            finalValue++;
        }
    }

    calculateAlarmDay = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                       value:finalValue
                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                          options:0];;
    NSLog(@"value is %@",calculateAlarmDay);

}
```

I am stuck with this stuff from last seven days. Please  tell me the solution. Thanks

Comment: pleaseusecamelcaseforyourmethodnames! ;)

Comment: Mmh, I don't know if it's related to your issue or not, but the docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSWeekCalendarUnit) say that `NSWeekCalendarUnit` is deprecated since iOS 8...

Comment: yes, sure I will use camcel case for my method name @NicolasMiari